# Continuity in topological spaces

Tags: general-topology

Let $(E,\theta)$ and $(F,\tau)$ two topological spaces, and $A\neq \emptyset$  a sub set from $F$.

let $f:E\to A$ and $i_A: A\to F$ the inclusion map.

Suppose that $i_A\circ f: E\to F$ is continuous and prove that $f$ is continuous.

I say: Let $\Omega$ be an open set from $A$ that there exists an open set $O$ from $F$ such that $\Omega= O\cap A$

$f^{-1}(\Omega)=f^{-1}(O\cap A)=f^{-1}(O)\cap f^{-1}(A)$

but I don't know to introduce $i_A\circ f$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $i_A\circ f$ is continuous we know that $(i_A\circ f)^{-1}(O)$ is an open set in $E$. Now note that:

$(i_A\circ f)^{-1}(O)=f^{-1}(i_A^{-1}(O))=f^{-1}(A\cap O)=f^{-1}(\Omega)$